# Azure Storage: container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync() exits app without Exception or success/fail

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I am following this Ms doc [Authorize access to blob and queue data with managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) to connect to Azure blob.

```
string containerEndpoint = 
    string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}", accountName, containerName);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());
try
{
    var task = await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(); // at this point app exist without exception. 
    string blobContents = "This is a block blob.";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobContents);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, stream);
    }
}
catch (RequestFailedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    throw;
}
```

As pointed on comment app exit without exception at `containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()`.

Comment: You're only catching `RequestFailedException`. Try adding a catch block for `Exception`, and see what it is throwing

Comment: There is no problem with this code on my side. What version of the assembly do you use?

Comment: As Andrew mentioned, catch the base `Exception` type so we can see if there's anything being thrown. That will cause any type of exception to be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue.

I found that's because my `async` function is not `await`ed.

```cs
async static Task CreateBlockBlobAsync()
{
    // ...
    var task = await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    // ...
}

// Call the function like this would produce your behavior
CreateBlockBlobAsync();

// Instead, await that function and everything goes well
await CreateBlockBlobAsync();
```